# Access User Control properties inside a jQuery Accordion

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to access the properies of my user control which is embedded within a jquery accordion.

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3>
    Blacklist Information</h3>
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlBlacklistInformation" runat="server">
        <CAMLiteUC:BlacklistInformation ID="ucBlacklistInformation" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
<h3>
    Customer Loyalty<asp:Label ID="lblBlacklisted" runat="server" Text="!" Visible="false"></asp:Label></h3>
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlCustomerLoyalty" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

For some reason the accordion is preventing me from accessing it, and once I remove it from the jQuery Accordion there seems to be no issue.

Would anyone be able to advise how to get this to work?

```
public partial class ucBlacklistInformation : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public String customerIDType { get; set; }
    public String customerIDNo { get; set; }

    public String userName { get; set; }
    public bool isDealer { get; set; }
```

Comment: Which property is it you are looking for, what is happening when you are trying to access it, are you getting an error message? is it just null? if its during a postback have you tried to see using fiddler to see what form values are getting put back to the server.

Comment: From the code behind, I'm trying to access properties such as ucBlacklistInformation.isDealer and ucBlacklistInformation.customerIDType, however I'm not able to see it at all in the intellisense

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding the solution. i know that when it used to happen to me it usually involved a mix of cleaning\reuilding &| restart VS &| restart machine

Comment: thanks, will give it a go on monday and see how it goes.